The twisted cubic and singular cubic surfaces they lie on.
$\newcommand\P{\mathbb P}\newcommand\C{\mathbb C}$
We know that the twisted cubic (space curve) is not a complete intersection but it is the intersection of a cubic surface and a quadric. But I cannot find a singular normal cubic surface in $\P^3$ for which the twisted cubic is a set-theoretic complete intersection on (i.e. it is the intersection of this cubic surface and another surface in $\P^3$) and for which this cubic surface has neither $(1:0:0:0)$ nor $(0:0:0:1)$ as its singular points. Am I missing something or is there an easy explanation to this?
Just to be more precise: My ground field is $\C$ (or any algebraically closed field of char. 0) and our twisted cubic curve in $\P^3$ is the parametrizable curve
$$\{(w:x:y:z) : w=u^3, x=u^2t, y=ut^2, z=t^3  \text{ for }(u:t) \in \P^1\}$$
Also, I am not looking for an example for which the cubic surface is smooth or with infinitely many singularities.

Indeed I just missed something sorry for the quite simple question. I got it:
The two surfaces defined by
$f=wx-y^2$
and
$g=wx^2-w^2y+z(-xy+z)-y(-y^2+xz)$
respectively will intersect into the twisted cubic.
The quadric defined by $f=0$ is smooth and the cubic surface $g=0$ is normal but singular at $(1:1:1:1)$ but not at $(1:0:0:0)$ nor at $(0:0:0:1)$.
